# before_save if attribute.present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, before-save

```
before_save :date_started_sets_deadline, if date_started.present?
```

I don't want this `before_save` to run if `:date_started == nil`. I've tried various versions of the above line so not sure if I have to change that or the method itself.

```
def date_started_sets_deadline
  if self.date_started > Date.tomorrow
    self.deadline = self.date_started
  end
end
```

I'm trying to avoid the error `NoMethodError (undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass): app/models/challenge.rb:35:in 'date_started_sets_deadline'` whenever a user tries to create a challenge without a `date_started`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `before_save` statement to the following:

`before_save :date_started_sets_deadline, if: :date_started?`

If you provide a `symbol` to the `if`, then `rails` evaluates it
in the context of the instance. By adding `?`, it is a auto generated method which is essentially same as `date_started.present?`.

Also, if the `date_started` is required within the `date_started_sets_deadline` implementation, I would also add the check explicitly instead of solely depending on adding the `if` condition on the callback logic.

```
def date_started_sets_deadline
  if self.date_started.present? && (self.date_started > Date.tomorrow)
    self.deadline = self.date_started
  end
end
```

Refer to [Using :if and :unless with a Symbol](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it will be putting a conditional if in side the method.

```
def date_started_sets_deadline
  if self.date_started != nil 
    if self.date_started > Date.tomorrow
     self.deadline = self.date_started
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Try this, I checked it on a personal project.

`before_save :date_started_sets_deadline, if: self.date_started.present?`

Comment: just made and edit, let me know if the works, with the `present?` method

Comment: Please check the latest one, I just did a similar thing on a personal project

Answer (score 1):

Another answer mentions providing the symbol to be called, I would recommend creating your own method to be that symbol so that you can include all the conditions you're interested in, ie.

```
before_save :set_deadline, if: :starts_after_tomorrow?

def starts_after_tomorrow?
  date_started? && date_started > Date.tomorrow
end

def set_deadline
  self.deadline = date_started
end
```

I think that's much cleaner than having the logic repeated in your `before_save` and setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the conditions and change the data inside the callback method.

```
before_save :date_started_sets_deadline

def date_started_sets_deadline
  if date_started.present? && self.date_started > Date.tomorrow
   self.deadline = self.date_started
  end
end
```

But i think it's a good idea to split this responsibilities. For example you can move the check inside another method.

```
before_save :set_deadline, if: :set_deadline?

def set_deadline?
  date_started.present? && date_started > Date.tomorrow
end

def set_deadline
  self.deadline = date_started
end
```

For simple conditions it's very hard to find good method names or it feels a little bit over engineered, so you can check it directly at callback definition with procs and lambdas. But you should use it carefully.

```
before_save :set_deadline, if: ->() { date_started.present? }

def set_deadline
  self.deadline = date_started if self.date_started > Date.tomorrow
end
```